# HTML5 Video playing no sound

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have working jsFiddle of 2 videos that toggle. The first video is a teaser which has no sound and the second video (click show top right) should play sound...

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="buttons">
<div class="show-button">Show</div>
<div id="infoToggler">
    <div class="play-button">Play</div>
    <div class="pause-button">Pause</div>
</div>
<div class="exit-button">Exit</div>
</div>
<video id="video-1" autoplay loop mute preload>
<source src="http://www.helloaerial.com/videos/new/webDemoAerial2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<div class="video-large">
<video id="video-2">
    <source src="https://www.bigcartel.com/videos/bgvid-1280x720-rf25-d0e7eb9e.mp4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/849y5fgs/8/

Cheers

Comment: Mate, the original video 2 at https://www.bigcartel.com/videos/bgvid-1280x720-rf25-d0e7eb9e.mp4v is already muted. Maybe that's why?

Comment: Man what a rookie - cheers bro! It's that time of night!

Comment: Get some sleep mate! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your code but what I found is, Your video file https://www.bigcartel.com/videos/bgvid-1280x720-rf25-d0e7eb9e.mp4v may be "only video file". It means ".mp4v" where "v" define video only. If you directly open this video on chrome browser(I tested on latest version), it will show the volume control disable, it means your video may not have audio with it. Please try with anothet mp4 video that have audio.

Another reason (assumption) is that for ".mp4v" , you should use another MIMETYPE not "video/mp4".